# I'm a new user can't reach my installation screen after uploading my worldpress file can anyone help also i will like to get a tutorial on how to play

Tags: local-installation

Any tip on uploading my wordpress file into my MAMPpro ..

Having issue locating the wordpress installation screen after uploading the file into the htdocs also can't reach the localhost screen on my webbroswer

I need help with guideline as am a new user